# Failed to save customer property with offiejs api at Mac outlook

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

```
var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(customPropsCallback);
function customPropsCallback(asyncResult) {
    var customProps = asyncResult.value;
    var myProp = customProps.get("myProp");
    customProps.set("otherProp", "value");
    customProps.saveAsync(saveCallback);
}
```

we cannot get the property after we used the above api to save property in office365 addin on mac outlook which works previously.
Note this issue only happened on Mac outlook.

Comment: Can you share the version of Mac Outlook you are using? By the way the custom property you set on the client takes sometime to get synced with the server. So if you are making any server side request you might have to wait for some time.

Comment: thanks for your response, we tested it on the Mac outlook inside fast version, also pls note this issue only happened when the event scheduled on mac outlooks, which worked at before versions.

Comment: actually we tested it some different versions outlook reently, same behavior. but office online and windows works well.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook for Mac does not support saving a calendar event.

> [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/compare-outlook-add-in-support-in-outlook-for-mac): Outlook for Mac does not support saving a meeting. The saveAsync method will fail when called from a meeting in compose mode.

So the custom properties, which you have set on the client will not be accessible on the exchange server until the calendar event is sent.

Custom properties should still be available on the same Outlook client, if you cannot get the custom property on the same Outlook client, then it is a bug in Outlook for Mac.